# Hot crab and Artichoke dip - can it be made in advance?

Tags: food-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

How much ahead of time could I put this dish together and refrigerate before heating to serve?
Should I freeze it if it is going to be longer than one or 2 days?

```
1  can(14 oz. / 400 gr) artichoke hearts, drained
1  package(8 oz. / 225 gr) cream cheese, softened
1  cup  (236 ml) mayonnaise
3/4  cup (180 ml) finely shredded Parmesan cheese
1/3  cup (80 ml) sliced green onions
1  package(8 oz. / 225 gr) flake-style imitation crabmeat, finely chopped
Crackers Keebler® Town House® Original
```

[Link to the crackers web page](http://www.keebler.com/product-keebler-town-house-original-crackers-1260.aspx)

directions

1. Chop artichoke hearts. Set aside.
2. In medium bowl stir together cream cheese and mayonnaise. Stir in artichoke hearts, Parmesan cheese and onions. Fold in imitation crabmeat.
3. Spoon into 9-inch pie plate or two 2-cup casseroles. Bake, uncovered, at 375 degrees F about 25 minutes or until heated through. Granish as desired. Serve with crackers.

Comment: I would suggest editing the title of this question to be more clear about what you're asking.